# Jenkins using script variable inside sh

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to declare a variable called output inside the `script` section of a Jenkins file and trying to use it like this

```
stages {
  stage('Deploy') {
    steps {
      script {
 
        output = 'output.log' 
        sh 'cd invoker && mvn clean install && mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.company.Deployer" -Dexec.args="qal ${GIT_COMMIT_HASH}" > ../${output}'
        echo readFile(output)
       }
     }        
   }
}
```

But I am getting this error: `script.sh: cannot create ../: Is a directory`. Which means that the variable is not getting populated. I tried both  `${output}` and `$output` but got the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In groovy single quotes (`''`) strings don't support [String Interpolation](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation) only double quotes (`""`) strings (GStrings) support it, and therefore your parameter does not get evaluated.
To solve the issue just use double quotes in your `sh` step:

```
 sh "cd invoker && mvn clean install && mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=\"com.company.Deployer\" -Dexec.args=\"qal ${GIT_COMMIT_HASH}\" > ../${output}"
```

Another option is to use the declarative pipeline [environment directive](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#setting-environment-variables) that is a part of the declarative pipeline syntax, which sets parameters (in addition to default ones) that will be loaded as environments variables to the shell execution environment.
So you can define the parameter in the `environment` block, and then use it in the script with the shell syntax for environment variables: `$PARAM`.
Something like:

```
pipeline {
   agent any
   environment {
       OUTPUT_FILE= 'output.log'
   }
   stages {
       stage('Use Global Parameter') {
           steps {
               sh 'cd invoker && mvn clean install && mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.company.Deployer" -Dexec.args="qal $GIT_COMMIT_HASH" > ../$OUTPUT_FILE'
               echo readFile(output)
           }
       }
   }
}
```